# Stop a TFS Workflow Transition if Fields are Empty

Tags: tfs

In a 'Release' workitem I have 2 custom date fields that indicate if software has been deployed to 2 possible locations.  The software may go to both or just one.

How can I restrict the transition of the workitem until at least one of the fields has a value.

```
    <TRANSITION from="Release" to="Done">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Software Deployed" />          
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="MyCompany.Environment1ReleaseDate">

        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="MyCompany.Environment2ReleaseDate">

        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

This is TFS2017 on premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not able to do this. You could not change a state based on filed rules. You could also **not able to skip/stop transitions by specific field volume**.

For System fields, there is some restriction for them. Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018#system-field-rules) for details:

> System fields have System.Name reference names, for example
>   System.Title and **System.State**. TFS restricts customization of
>   these fields, except for these instances:

Transitions define the valid progressions and regressions between states. **Users can specify only those states that are valid based on the transitions** that you define for the current state.

In the other word, Transitions tell the TFS which state can be followed by the current one.

A transition always has a from and to state. You could not **ignore** or skip the transition.

For more details of this related concept, you could take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Workflow design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops#workflow-design-guidelines)